# Stored procedure if mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```html
create procedure update_keyoffice(out p_key varchar(30),out p_hostname varchar(30))
begin
 declare p_keyoff varchar(30);
 select keyoff into p_keyoff from masterpc where keyoffice = p_key; 
 if(p_keyoff = p_key) then
  insert into keyofficehistory (id,keyoff,hostname,datecreate) values
  (null,p_key,p_hostname,now())
 end if
end
```

error

> SQL query:
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE update_keyoffice( out p_key varchar( 30 ) , out
>   p_hostname varchar( 30 ) ) BEGIN DECLARE p_keyoff varchar( 30 ) ;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

While defining stored procedures and triggers, you have to use custom `delimiter` which, it seems, is missing in your code.

Change your code as below:

```
delimiter //

-- your stored procedure code here

-- but don't forget to use new delimiter after end statement
end; //

-- now reset delimiter
delimiter ;
```

**Refer to**:
[CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)